# How to check that fscanf() returns valid string in C?

Tags: c, string, scanf

I have a C / fscanf() question.  FULL DISCLAIMER: I am CS student, working on an assignment.  My code works, but the graders will compile our submissions with using the GCC "all errors and warnings" option:

```
gcc -Wall yourCodeHere.c
```

My code works, but I'm getting a warning which bugs me... and could lead to problems with the grader.  My code is simple, it scans each line of a file into a string, then tosses that string to a function:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void printString(char* string){
    printf("file line is:  \"%s\"\n", string);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    char *myFile = argv[1];
    FILE *targetFile;
    targetFile = fopen(myFile, "r");

    if (targetFile == NULL) {
        // some problem with the input file
        return -1;
    } else {
        char* string;
        while (fscanf(targetFile, "%s\n", string) != EOF){
            printString(string);
        }
    }
    fclose(targetFile);
    return 1;
}
```

The warning is:

```
$ gcc -Wall myCode.c
myCode.c: In function ‘main’:
myCode.c:21:4: warning: ‘string’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
    printString(string);
    ^
$
```

I get what the compiler is trying to say:  "*What if 'string' is not holding valid data?*"  Its a valid point; I'm kinda assuming that every line of the input file will produce a working string.

So: how to check this and get rid of that annoying warning?  I note that fscanf() returns the number of items successfully scanned, so I tried this:

```
    int num = 1;    // initialize to something >0
    while (num = (fscanf(targetFile, "%s\n", string) != EOF) > 0){
        printString(string);
    }
```

But that produced ***two*** warnings:

```
$ gcc -Wall myCode.c
myCode.c: In function ‘main’:
myCode.c:21:3: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
   while (num = (fscanf(targetFile, "%s\n", string) != EOF) > 0){
   ^
myCode.c:22:4: warning: ‘string’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
    printString(string);
    ^
$
```

Plus, I worry that this would cause the program to stop reading the file too early if fscanf() returned 0 for some valid reason.

So...  Not certain how to get around this.  In Java, I'd simply say "if(string != NULL) ..." and move on.  But you can't do that in C.  There must be some quick way of checking that fscanf() grabs a valid string before I call the external function.

Anyone know a fix?

Thanks!
-Pete

PS - Apologies if this is more a GCC question than a C question.  :(

Comment: `char* string;` --> `char string[1024];`

Comment: `char *string` creates a pointer to a string. It does not allocate memory to hold that string. You could use `char string[256]` or `char *string = malloc(...)`.

Comment: Your code segfaults for me when run as-is against a text file that just contains a few lines, because as others have said, you're not allocating memory to hold the string. I don't know what your input is supposed to be (make sure to include that criteria in your question next time), but I'm not sure how you didn't catch that your code segfaults before asking here about a compiler warning.

Comment: Also as an aside I suggest `while (fscanf(targetFile, "%s\n", string) == 1)` because your version will fail if the return value is `0`. That might not ever do so for a `%s` input, but when you are scanning numeric types, or more than one string, it is important to check that the number of arguments converted matches the request, so it is better practice.

Comment: `char *string creates a pointer to a string` Which String exactly?

Comment: @markgz  Ohhhhhhh... of course!  The moment I glanced at your comment, the problem with my code hit me like a ton of bricks.  I keep forgetting that C requires you a allocate memory for everything.  Its an annoying habit to learn.  Thank you!

Comment: @RandomDavis  Thanks, I appreciate that you actually took the time to run my code.  Mine didn't seg fault, but its useful to know that yours did.  I've added the malloc() and free() commands, and everything looks good now.  Thanks!

Comment: @WeatherVane  Nice!  Thanks!  Comments like yours are why I love this site!

Comment: Final remark, I would not put `\n` inside the format string. Most of the format specifiers ignore any leading whitespace anyway (notably not `%c` where you would use `" %c"` with a space, which will make it too ignore any leading whitespace).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to check that fscanf() returns valid string in C?

1) Insure space is provided to save the data 2) Limit the amount of data read 3) test the result of the input  funciton.

```
    // #1 Provide space  `char* string` is simple a pointer with an uninitialized value
    // char* string;
    // Select a reasonable upper bound: recommend 2x expected max size
    char string[100];

    // #2 Limit width to reading up to 99 characters, 
    // 1 less than buffer size as `fscanf()` will append a null character
    // while (fscanf(targetFile, "%s\n", string) != EOF){
    // while (fscanf(targetFile, "%99s\n", string) != EOF){

    // #3 Check against the desired success value, 
    //   do not check against one of the undesired values
    while (fscanf(targetFile, "%99s\n", string) == 1) {
```

Answer (score 2):

`string` in your code is a pointer rather than an array.  There is no memory allocated for `fscanf` to copy the characters into.  Changing it to a character array will work as would `string = malloc(X);` where X is the number of bytes you want to allocate.  Remember that you'll need an extra byte for the '\0' termination of the string.  Also remember that you have no idea how big the line of test could be and `fscanf` will just copy bytes without caring about length, which brings up another issue -- how is `fscanf` supposed to know to copy an entire line rather than just a word or a character?  You should look into that!

Comment: I up voted your Answer, but you shouldn't say `Changing it to a character array will work` because you never know why he/she uses `char*` and not `char[]`

Comment: Thanks nategoose, you're so right.  This malloc() / free() habit is a tough one to pick up, especially after learning Java first.  Appreciate the help!